# Difference between web client and web service?

Tags: android, web-services, webclient

Recently, I'm developing android app which must be connected to server (retrieve data from database and write data to database). Directly connecting app with database is obviously too risky (considering security) so I have been searching for another solution. To connect with database I have to use web service but I have found tutorial that uses web client and uri, "calls" PHP files on server and retrieves information with them. So, now I'm wondering what is the difference between this approach and web service. Are they both good solutions or one is better?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you have a REST API implemented on the Server? There are plenty of Android libraries that help you handling such calls.

Comment: The question is theoretical. I'm just looking for explanation of the difference between web client and web service and maybe what is better or more secure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having web client directly connected to data base is truly risky. Reason is that beside address of server you need to give client (application) credentials to get access to database. So client has to have address of server, database username and database password. On the other hand using web service will ensure that only your program is accessing these informations on server side and your database login informations will be safe. **In conclusion don't connect to database directly trough client. Make web service layer in the middle and your database will be safe!**

Web client is program on device that connects to server's program(web service).

Comment: I don't know if you understand me well. I'm following this tutorial: [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jF3D__ibrx8&list=PLCuRg51-gw5VqYchUekCqxUS9hEZkDf6l&index=19)

Comment: In your case php program is web service and android application is web client.

Comment: You mean considering link I gave you?  That in the tutorial php program is web service and android app web client?